# Object orientation in Scala

Tags: scala

From Martin Odersky's Scala course I have the following Exercise (this a video exercise in which answer is given):

"
Provide an implementation of the abstract class Nat that represents
non-negative integers

Do not use standard numerical classes in this implementation.
Rather, implement a sub-object and a sub-class.

One for the number zero, the other for strictly prositive numbers.
"

Here is the code :

```
abstract class Nat {
  def isZero : scala.Boolean
  def predecessor : Nat
  def successor = new Succ(this)
  def + (that : Nat) : Nat
  def - (that : Nat) : Nat
}

object Zero extends Nat {
  def isZero = true
  def predecessor = throw new Error("0.predecessor")
  def + (that: Nat) = that
  def - (that: Nat) = if(that.isZero) this else throw new Error("negative number")
}

class Succ(n : Nat) extends Nat {
  def isZero = false
  def predecessor = n
  def +(that : Nat) = new Succ(n + that)
  def -(that: Nat) = n - that.predecessor
}
```

Within a Scala worksheet I have :

```
object NatTests {
  new Successor(Zero).+(new Successor(Zero))  
}
```

Which returns a new Sucessor. I don't think I'm understanding this code fully as I should be able to add non zero objects without extending the code ? If so, how is this accomplished ?

Comment: For background, look into Peano Arithmetic and / or Church Numerals so you understand the concept being implemented here.

Answer (score 6):

You *are* able to add non zero numbers / objects without extending any of the classes `Nat`, `Zero`, or `Succ`. When you use an object `natObj` of type `Nat` and construct a new object `new Succ(natObject)` that new object represents a number that is one higher than the number that `natObj` represents.

Maybe being able to view the objects, makes this a bit clearer:

```
abstract class Nat {
  def isZero : Boolean
  def predecessor : Nat
  def successor = new Succ(this)
  def + (that : Nat) : Nat
  def - (that : Nat) : Nat
}

object Zero extends Nat {
  def isZero = true
  def predecessor = throw new Error("0.predecessor")
  def + (that: Nat) = that
  def - (that: Nat) = if(that.isZero) this else throw new Error("negative number")

  override def toString = "0 => Zero"
}

class Succ(n : Nat) extends Nat {
  def isZero = false
  def predecessor = n
  def + (that : Nat) = new Succ(n + that)
  def - (that: Nat) = if (that.isZero) this else n - that.predecessor

  override def toString = {
    def findNumber(nat: Nat): Int = 
      if (nat.isZero) 0 
      else 1 + findNumber(nat.predecessor)
    val number = findNumber(this)
    String.valueOf(number) + " => " + 
            ((1 to number) fold ("Zero")) ( (s,_) => "Succ(" + s + ")")
  }
}
```

Now your Scala worksheet will show you the number an object represents and its internal structure:

```
object NatTests extends App {
  val nat0 = Zero                                 
  val nat1 = new Succ(Zero)                       
  val nat2 = new Succ(nat1) // or new Succ(new Succ(Zero))
  val nat3 = new Succ(nat2) // or new Succ(new Succ(new Succ(Zero)))

  println(nat0)             //> 0 => Zero
  println(nat1)             //> 1 => Succ(Zero)
  println(nat2)             //> 2 => Succ(Succ(Zero))
  println(nat3)             //> 3 => Succ(Succ(Succ(Zero)))
  println(nat2 + nat2)      //> 4 => Succ(Succ(Succ(Succ(Zero))))
  println(nat3 + nat2)      //> 5 => Succ(Succ(Succ(Succ(Succ(Zero)))))
}
```

Comment: the to String was really helpful. so we never use numbers at all ? its just bunch of objects glued together ? instead of bits, we are using notation to represent the natural numbers ? is that wat is going on here ?

Comment: @bicepjai: Yes, that's exactly what's going on. Some languages (but not Scala) optimize these "church encoded numbers" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding so that they are internally stored as "bits" but appear to the programmer as "objects glued together".

Comment: I really love all the puzzly way of using lambda calculus for programming :) but I am having hard time to wrap my mind on how is this better than imperative programming say in terms of efficiency ?

Comment: @bicepjai: It's *not* better than imperative programming in terms of efficiency ): *but* it makes reasoning about your code so much easier that it's worth the overhead - especially, when it comes to concurrent and distributed systems.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely expected to implement them recursively

I'm not sure of the exact syntax, but it'd be something like this

```
def +(that : Nat) = (this.predecessor + that.successor)
def -(that: Nat) = if (that.isZero) this else (this.predecessor - that.predecessor)
```

Also since your objects are immutable, there's no real reason to create a new one each time.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would write it:

```
sealed trait Nat {
  def isZero : scala.Boolean
  def predecessor : Nat
  def successor = Succ(this)
  def + (that : Nat) : Nat
  def - (that : Nat) : Nat  = 
       if (that.isZero) this else this.predecessor - that.predecessor
}

case object Zero extends Nat {
  def isZero = true
  def predecessor = sys.error("predecessor of zero")
  def + (that: Nat) = that
}

case class Succ(predecessor : Nat) extends Nat {
  def isZero = false
  def +(that : Nat) = this.predecessor + that.successor
}
```